GeoServer Loader class not loading SLD styles
I have a problem when importing styles into GeoServer via our import functionality that takes a backup ZIP file with a workspace file structure, containing styles as well, and loads it with GeoServerLoader.
The GeoServerLoader correctly loads the XML files, but SLD files are omitted, thefore we are getting an error when trying to open such a style:

When debugging, the SLD files are indeed present in the loadStyles() styles parameter.

However, they are missing in the GeoServer styles directory in Tomcat server.
Does anyone know how to import SLD style files properly as well? The Loader seems to ignore it.

Thinking out loud and making a guess... are you transferring the data directory from an OS where files are case-insensitive, to one where they are case-sensitive instead?
